# C++ How to search inside an array of structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, struct

I'm having a problem with searching inside of an array of structs.  When I run this code through the debugger, the for loop does not advance through the array, rather it gets stuck on the first element of the array and continuously compares the first value to the configSource variable.  There are 44 elements in the array.  It seems like I'm doing the search correctly, is there a different syntax I should be using on an array made up of structs?

I am basically a beginner, and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

```
int arraySize;
std::wstring configSource;

struct NamedGuid 
{
    std::wstring name;
    GUID const *guid;
};

NamedGuid format_guid_names[] = 
{
    {TEXT("CompNTSCCCIR"), &INPUT_CompNTSCCCIR},
    {TEXT("CompNTSCSqPixel"), &INPUT_CompNTSCSqPixel},
    {TEXT("SVideoNTSCCCIR"), &INPUT_SVideoNTSCCCIR},
    .
    etc...
    .
    {TEXT("DigitalHD"),  &INPUT_DigitalHD},
    {TEXT("HDSDI"),  &INPUT_HDSDI},
    {TEXT("HDSDI10Bit"),  &INPUT_HDSDI10Bit},
    {TEXT(""), nullptr} 
};

long OpenDevice (std::wstring argTemps)
{
    //A lot of code which isn't relevant

    //Parses the command line arguments and creates a string that
    //is searched for in the array
    configSource = parseArgs(argTemp);

    int arraySize = _countof(format_guid_names); 

    GUID sourceGuid = get_format_guid_by_name(configSource, arraySize);

    hSrc = dpSetDeviceInput(hDevice, &sourceGuid, 0, 0);

    //More code that isn't relevant
}
GUID get_format_guid_by_name(std::wstring configSource, int arraySize)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
        if (format_guid_names[index].name == configSource)
            return *format_guid_names[index].guid;
    }
    return *format_guid_names[arraySize - 1].guid;
 }
```

Edited because I realized I had forgotten to pass the size of the array to the function, but the same problem is still happening.

Comment: Have you checked `std::find_if`?

Comment: No, I had no idea that existed, I'll check it out.

Comment: What is the type of configSource?

Comment: std::wstring, editing my post to show this

Comment: Put breakpoint inside get_format_guid_by_name and see what it do.

Comment: What makes you think the loop is not advancing?

Comment: It keeps comparing configSource to the first element in the array, regardless of the index value.  This is the element being compared:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20435654/Capture.PNG

Comment: Why shouldn't I use `==` on strings?  Isn't the only difference is that `==` returns a boolean value and `compare` returns an integer?

Comment: @BradRicketts `GUID get_format_guid_by_name(std::wstring, int)`  You specify parameters without their names?  Then you do this:  `GUID sourceGuid = get_format_guid_by_name(configSource, arraySize);`  So you're passing values, but in the function, you don't use the parameters for anything since they are unnamed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see, thanks.  Made the change in my code, and edited the OP, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your get_format_guid_by_name function is not naming its input arguments, which is why you are having to assign to global variables in order to call the function. You should remove the global definitions and name your input arguments to the function:

```
GUID get_format_guid_by_name(const std::wstring& configSource, int arraySize)
```

That does not solve your problem though (just makes it easier to debug).

You say 'it gets stuck on the first element of the array and continuously compares the first value to the configSource variable'. That tells me that configSource does not == any of the names in your format_guid_names array. Your for loop looks correct.

If I were debugging this loop, I would print out index, format_guid_names[index].name and configSource to the console before the 'if' statement check. That will tell you exactly what is being compared and in what order.

Comment: Well, I did what you said, and it is comparing correctly.  I guess I'm not using the Visual Studio debugger correctly.